# Why do I need theese specific packages in my ejected CRA project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

Bootstrapped CRA 3.0 app and then ejected.
Inspecting my `package.json`.
Found multiple packages usages of which are not really clear to me.

`"semver": "6.0.0"`
Why do I need this? No usages found in `config/*` nor `scripts/*`. It seems like an artifact of `react-scripts` validation-like logic for related packages, so it looks like a piece of bloat in my *application dependencies*.

`"react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.0"`
Polyfills for IEs and etc.? OK, but why a separate package? It's frightening to me to use some unknown package on top of `core-js` or `babel-polyfill`. And again, no usages found in an initial code base.

**P.S. I'm not asking what these packages are, I'm asking why do I see them being unused in ejected scripts**

Update: `react-app-polyfill/jsdom` is used in Jest setup files

Comment: In order to hide that kind of packages and configs, you have CRA and you shouldn't eject it till you really need to. Probably they are needed for some features of CRA that you don't use or to fix some bug that you are not aware of

Comment: you can always check the docs for these packages on npm

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı in my case I really needed to eject

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I added clarification to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create-react-app` uses a package named [`react-scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) which hides all the different packages it uses underneath.

When you `eject` an application, the dependencies used by `react-scripts` are [copied over](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/4b8b38bf7c55326f8d51ea9deeea76d7feee307d/packages/react-scripts/scripts/eject.js#L208) to your own `package.json`. But for some scripts like the eject, various sections are removed using babel annotation like `@remove-on-eject-begin`. The dependencies used in these sections persist even after you eject.

This is how you find packages like `semver` that are not used anywhere in your application code. In an *unejected* create react app, that package would be used for verifying the [semantic versions](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/f5b0aac4116fe58694db7c8996c4fd7da4821b9a/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyPackageTree.js) before ejecting.

These are safe to remove now. But they would not be factored into the static bundle you are creating anyhow.